# Why does -like operator in Powershell works without wildcard?

Tags: powershell, syntax, scripting

As far as I know this operator works only with wildcard syntax but why in this case it actually worked out?

```
PS C:\Users\Danie\Pictures> Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -Like ".jpg"}
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/3/2020      1:55        1253954 16009807808_f3f4709393_k.jpg
```

Comment: when you leave off the wildcard chars, the `-like` operator acts as a `-eq` operator.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey With one added difference - `-like` _always_ coerces both operands to `[string]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - ooo! i had not thot of that ... it makes sense, tho. thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

It works out because the `Extension` property value in your case is *exactly* `.jpg`.

As [Lee_Dailey mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270246/why-does-like-operator-in-powershell-works-without-wildcard#comment108391514_61270246), using `-like` without any wildcard characters in your pattern is functionally equivalent to `$string -eq $pattern`.

---

### Why use `-like` then?!

In your case there's no functional difference because `Extension` is already of type `[string]` - but there *is* one good reason to use `-like` over `-eq` when doing string comparisons - and that is that `-like` *only does string comparison*, meaning that you can guarantee both operands are treated as strings during comparison.

With `-eq`, the comparison being made depends entirely on the type of the left-hand side ( or **lhs**) operand:

```bsh
PS C:\> $null -eq ""  # $null is not a string
False
PS C:\> $null -like ""  # But -like attempts to convert $null to [string], we get an empty one
True
```

This goes for any operand type, not just `$null`:

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-Item C:\Windows) -eq 'C:\Windows'    # [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] is also not [string]
False
PS C:\> (Get-Item C:\Windows) -like 'C:\Windows'  # But `-like` treats it as one
True
```